# Configure a custom date to use as starting point in the datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ui.bootstrap

I'm trying to configure the datepicker from angular-ui.bootstrap to have a starting point date when user pops up the datepicker.

I found out this line of code actually works.

```
$scope.date = new Date(1980-12-12);
```

It actually put the value at the input-box and also the picker. But I want my input-box to be empty initially. Instead I want the placeholder to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the placeholder attribute.

Something like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{date}}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use placeholder attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" placeholder="{{date}}" value="" ... />
```